# Text to speech in Excel visual basic macro

Tags: vba, excel, text-to-speech

I've been trying to write a macro in excel that can recognize changing values of a column of cells and trigger an alert using text to speech  for the corresponding row different column. Below are two sets of code I've used and have produced results, however I need to finetune the code as I've run into a few obstacles:

the first code updates too frequently (each time there is an external update to the sheet, fires off this code).

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim myText As String
For Each c In Range("bf4:bf45")
If c.Value = 1 Then
myText = c.Offset(0, -57).Text
Application.Speech.Speak (myText)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

the second code fires off only when I manually hit the enter key in the range defined.

```
 Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
 If target = 1 And _
 target.Column = 58 And _
 target.Row >= 4 And _
 target.Row <= 45 Then _
 Application.Speech.Speak target.Offset(0, -57).Text

 End Sub
```

I am trying to add code that can either provide a timer for this code ( so every 4 minutes the text to speech alert will go off) or each time the defined column's values change there will be an auto text to speech alert of corresponding row.

Thanks!

Edited to include code of worksheet calculate and code for .ontime

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim myText As String
For Each c In Range("bf4:bf45")
If c.Value = 1 Then
myText = c.Offset(0, -57).Text
Application.Speech.Speak (myText)
End If
Next
End Sub



 Public Sub Updatetextspeech()
'Clock that prompts running of text to speech alert
 Sheets("ALERTS").Select
 Call myText
 Nexttick = Now + TimeValue("00:03:00")
 Application.OnTime Nexttick, "Updatetextspeech"

        If Time >= TimeValue("16:00:00") Then
        Application.OnTime Nexttick, "Updatetextspeech", , False
    End If
End Sub
```

Additional code updated 9/12/2014 in response to DavidZemens code

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldValues As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Sub Main()

'## Define our range to monitor, modify as needed
 Set rng = Sheets("ALERTS").Range("be4:be45")

'## Store its values in the array
oldValues = rng.Value

'## Initialize the UpdateTextSpeech
' I use a shorter interval for debugging, modify as needed
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "UpdateTextSpeech"


End Sub
```

For some reason below section of the code sub "updatetextspeech"  is causing alot of breaks, of the different code I tried I would either get object not defined, or compile errors, or argument not optional below are the few different codes for the application.speech I tried
    Sub UpdateTextSpeech()

```
 Dim r As Long

 **'## Iterate the range**
 For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
 'Check if its value has changed AND the adjacent cell
 If rng.Cells(r, 1).Value <> oldValues(r, 1) And rng.Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 Then

    **'This is where your speech app goes:** 
     Application.speech.speak.cells(r,1).text  'OR

    Application.speech.speak.value.text        'OR

    Application.speech.speak (updatetextspeech).text  'OR

    End If
 Next

'Provide a way to escape the OnTime loop:
 If MsgBox("Continue monitoring cell changes?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
'update the "old" values
oldValues = rng.Value
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Updatetextspeech"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Look in to using `Application.OnTime` in a continuous loop?

Comment: @DavidZemens I tried 
    Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target = 1 And _
    target.Column = 58 And _
    target.Row >= 4 And _
    target.Row <= 45 Then _
    Application.Speech.Speak target.Offset(0, -57).Text
    Nexttick = Now + TimeValue("00:03:00")
    Application.OnTime Nexttick, "worksheet_change"
    
            If Time >= TimeValue("16:00:00") Then
            Application.OnTime Nexttick, "worksheet_change", ,          False
    End If
End Sub                                                               But that did not work.

Comment: Can you clarify "corresponding row different column"?  This doesn't make sense to me.  Also, can you clarify what "external update to the sheet" is?  Is this a shared workbook?  Are their formulas that reference external sources?  Is this WB linked to a database?

Comment: @n8 "corresponding row different column" eg. a change in cell B1 will trigger text to speech for A1.                               External update I have live data feeding into other columns cells in the spreadsheet from external sources and each time the data updates the speech to text macro fires                      Not linked to a database, and yes formulas that reference external sources.

Comment: OK, then I see two issues: a timer would potentially happen after several changes to the sheet, so would you want to read all of the changes that occurred since the last "refresh"?  And if you want to hear changes to your sheet, why is it too frequent when it happens?  Maybe you should isolate the speech trigger to only certain changes.

Comment: @n8,@DavidZemens Lets say B1 is a cell that has a formula with multiple variables, if true "1", if not "0". all cells are "0" until they qualify the formula then cells will display "1", which should trigger the text to speech alert.There are a ton of data points in other columns ie. C,D,E that are updating each second, and are triggering the text to speech for cells in column B that have a "1"

Comment: formula evaluation doesn't trigger the sheet's `_Change` event :) Can you put your code with the `OnTime` method in the original question? It is ok -- even preferable -- to **edit** your quesiton to include additional details, becaues it's often very difficult to read code snippets in the comments.

Comment: @DavidZemens  Ohk, I can have the range = a cell that has the formula evaluation, so the range only has either an "1' or "0"

Comment: Yes, sure you can. But when that range's *value* "changes" as a result of the underlying formula calculation, that calculation does not trigger the worksheet `Change` event. That is your first problem. Also, you need to specify: 1) How often do you need to look at each cell(s)?  How many cell(s) do you need to examine? What if the cell value changes more than once per interval (should your application read *all* changes to the cell, or just the *final* value)? etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens Do I need to include the logic formula in the vb Script? I am examining about 45 cells. yes whatever the cell is whaen the timer goes off is what should be determined if text to speech or not. Each interval text to speech should read all final values.

Comment: @DavidZemens Hey just saw this awesome code you posted. Will review and digest,Thanks!

Comment: @DavidZemens hi david, I keep getting Object variable not set, or compile errors when I try to use code for the speech app such as: "Application.Speech.Speak rng.Value.Offset(0, -57).Text" and       "Application.Speech.Speak r.Offset(0, -57).Text" error is "invalid qualifier"   and when I use the code included for your message box app, I get Object variable not set.

Comment: Please revise your original question (above) to show the code you are *currently* attempting to implement and I will debug from there. It is hard to see whawt you're actually doing unless you can show the full code you're using.  I will check back in the morning.

Comment: @DavidZemens any thoughts on the compile error issue I had with the code? Seems like " For r = 1 To rng.Rows.count " in the UpdateTextSpeech module is not recognized as defined

Comment: Try `Application.speech.speak Cells(r,1).Text`. You have an errant `.` between `Speak` and `Cells`. Why would you put that there?  You wouldn't do `Debug.Print.Cells(r,1).Text`, so for the same reason you would not do `Application.Speech.Speak.Cells(r,1).Text` :)

Comment: @DavidZemens I tried Application.Speech.Speak Cells(r, 1).Text  but still get a compile error on the For r = 1 To rng.Rows.count declaration. Good point, didn't see that .

Comment: You need to run the `Main` procedure, otherwise `rng Is Nothing` and that would probably raise some sort of error.  If you try to run the other procedure on its own, it would probably fail.

Comment: @davidZemens I will try that, can I call the (main) procedure to the (UpdateTextSpeech) so it can recognize the dec.?

Comment: @davidZemens Great! I tried those corrections and it is working! It is only speaking the wrong column, I need to fiddle with why its doing that.

Comment: I think right now you have it to speak the cells in the column that are being monitored. To speak some other cell values, use the `Offset` method, e.g., `Cells(r, 1).Offset(,3)` would say the value 3 cells to the right, etc.

Comment: @davidZemens  The code works well, and the code written now offsets to the right column, however it offsets to the alert row+3 rows up. so eg B3 will offset to A1.

Comment: I'm confident that you can figure out how to use the `Offset(_ROW_OFFSET, _COLUMN_OFFSET_)` (where _row_offset_ and _column_offset_ represent the number of cells to offset, and a negative value would be left/above whereas a positive value is right/below)  method to fix that.  If my answer has assisted you, please do consider upvoting it or "accepting" it.  Cheers.

Comment: @DavidZemens The offset adjustment works great!Im only curious why it offsets to the right column but 3 rows above? OK will do, Thank you! Also if I want to replace the .ontime message box killswitch with a manual .ontime killswitch would that work? eg.  Application.OnTime Nexttick, "Updatetextspeech", , False

Comment: I think the range you define starts in row 4 iirc, so it's `cells(1, 1)`  would actually be in the 4th row relative to the entire worksheet.

Comment: @DavidZemens Ahh I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try something like this.

First, declare a module-level variable to represent the range of cells you want to monitor, and also their values can be stored as a module level variant.

We'll initially store the values. Then we start our timer loop using `Application.OnTime` method.  Each interval we will *compare* the current values to the values stored at the last interval. If the value has changed *and if* the formula equals `1`, then you can do the speech. A prompt will ask the user if s/he wants to continue. If yes, then we store the new values in the variant and those will be compared against the next interval.

I use a shorter interval, and a message box instead of the speech application, but you should be able to modify this.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldValues As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Sub Main()

'## Define our range to monitor, modify as needed
Set rng = Sheets("ALERTS").Range("A2:A10")

'## Store its values in the array
oldValues = rng.Value

'## Initialize the UpdateTextSpeech
' I use a shorter interval for debugging, modify as needed
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "UpdateTextSpeech"


End Sub
Sub UpdateTextSpeech()

Dim r As Long

'## Iterate the range
For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    'Check if its value has changed AND the adjacent cell
    If rng.Cells(r, 1).Value <> oldValues(r, 1) And rng.Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 Then

        'This is where your speech app goes:
        MsgBox rng.Cells(r, 1).Address & " has changed." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Old value: " & oldValues(r, 1) & vbCrLf & _
            "New value: " & rng.Cells(r, 1).Value

    End If
Next

'Provide a way to escape the OnTime loop:
If MsgBox("Continue monitoring cell changes?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    'update the "old" values
    oldValues = rng.Value
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Updatetextspeech"
End If


End Sub
```